# subprocess (launch ssh process in background) communicate hang if enable stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ssh, subprocess

I have next code, it will do next:

1. subprocess for `ssh -f -M` to let ssh launch a shared socket in background
2. As above is in background, so for the second ssh connection we could just reuse the socket `/tmp/control-channel` to connect ssh server without password.

**test.py:**

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import stat

ssh_user = "my_user"       # change to your account
ssh_passwd = "my_password" # change to your password

try:
    os.remove("/tmp/control-channel")
except:
    pass

# prepare passwd file
file = open("./passwd","w")
passwd_content = f"#!/bin/sh\necho {ssh_passwd}"
file.write(passwd_content)
file.close()
os.chmod("./passwd", stat.S_IRWXU)

# setup shared ssh socket, put it in background
env = {'SSH_ASKPASS': "./passwd", 'DISPLAY':'', 'SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE':'force'}
args = ['ssh', '-f', '-o', 'LogLevel=ERROR', '-x', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=30', '-o', 'ControlPersist=300', '-o', 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'ServerAliveInterval=15', '-MN', '-S', '/tmp/control-channel', '-p', '22', '-l', ssh_user, 'localhost']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, env=env,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
#        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,   # uncomment this line to enable stderr will make subprocess hang
        stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        start_new_session=True)
sout, serr = process.communicate()
print(sout)
print(serr)

# use shared socket
args2 = ['ssh', '-o', 'LogLevel=ERROR', '-o', 'ControlPath=/tmp/control-channel', '-p', '22', '-l', ssh_user, 'localhost', 'uname -a']
process2 = subprocess.Popen(args2,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
content, _ = process2.communicate()
print(content)
```

**execution:**

```
$ python3 test.py
b''
None
b'Linux shmachine 4.19.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.249-2 (2022-06-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux\n'
```

So far so good, just if I uncomment `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` in the first subprocess, it will hang:

```
$ python3 test.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    sout, serr = process.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 926, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I wonder what's the problem here?

My environment:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
```

UPDATE: I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116952/getting-race-condition-using-stderr-pipe-with-popen-communicate) which similar to my issue, but no answer.

UPDATE2: Change `communicate` to `wait` makes it work, but the `pipe size which wait use` surely less than `memory size which communicate use`, so I still wonder why I can't make it work with `communicate`.

Comment: Works on Fedora with OpenSSH 8.8p1 and Python 3.8 (the oldest I have installed). The answer mentioning a bug fixed in the meantime seems quite plausible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the stdout pipe set, just leave the stderr there to have a minimal check, and finally use strace to confirm it's the bug of old ssh which fixed in Y2020 in ssh 8.4. So python did correct behavior...

1. I see it stuck as next:

```
$ strace python3 test.py
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, 0x1744f00, 8192)                = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26779, si_uid=1001, si_status=0, si_utime=1, si_stime=0} ---
read(3,
```

2. 

```
$ sudo lsof -a -c python -d 3
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
python3 26778 nxa13855    3r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 9186593 pipe
```

3. 

```
$ ls -l "/proc/26778/fd/3"
lr-x------ 1 nxa13855 atg 64 Oct  5 20:22 /proc/26778/fd/3 -> 'pipe:[9186593]'
$ lsof | grep 9186593
python3   26778                   nxa13855    3r     FIFO               0,12      0t0    9186593 pipe
ssh       26783                   nxa13855    2w     FIFO               0,12      0t0    9186593 pipe
```

4. This means the `ssh -f` did not close stderr when put the ssh to background, so `communicate` can't read a EOF of stderr then hangs as next:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 929, in communicate
stderr = self.stderr.read()
```

And I confirm it with [openssh commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/d14fe25e6c3b89f8af17e2894046164ac3b45688)

Answer (score 0):

The answer really just hides in the python documention [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), and within the documention of `Popen.communicate`, reads the following:

`Note: The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.`

Therefore, a (potentially) working solution (since I don't really have a working SSH to test on), would be to add a `timeout` to the `communicate` call.

Comment: But we need the stderr data, and the stderr data is not big, just next: `Warning: Permanently added '172.17.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.` The `timeout` makes the program never could meet my requirement, as it's 100% reproduceable with my example, means if I use timeout, the program becomes meanless to me.

Comment: And in fact after I add `LogLevel=ERROR` when call ssh, there is no stderr print

Comment: OK. I'll look into it.

Comment: Edit: I saw an accepted answer so good luck with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ssh -f` command will continue to run in the background even after the `communicate()` method is called. This is because the `communicate()` method only waits for the process to finish writing to its standard output and standard error streams. It does not wait for the process to actually terminate.

When you redirect the standard error stream of the `ssh -f` command to its standard output stream, the `communicate()` method will never return. This is because the `ssh -f` command will continue to write to its standard output stream as long as it is running.

To fix this problem, you need to either:

1. **Call the `process.terminate()` method to terminate the `ssh -f` command explicitly.**
2. **Use the `timeout` keyword argument to the `communicate()` method to specify a timeout after which the `communicate()` method will return even if the process is still running.**

Here is an example of how to fix the problem using the `process.terminate()` method:

```py
import subprocess
import os
import stat

ssh_user = "my_user"       # change to your account
ssh_passwd = "my_password" # change to your password

try:
    os.remove("/tmp/control-channel")
except:
    pass

# prepare passwd file
file = open("./passwd","w")
passwd_content = f"#!/bin/sh\necho {ssh_passwd}"
file.write(passwd_content)
file.close()
os.chmod("./passwd", stat.S_IRWXU)

# setup shared ssh socket, put it in background
env = {'SSH_ASKPASS': "./passwd", 'DISPLAY':'', 'SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE':'force'}
args = ['ssh', '-f', '-o', 'LogLevel=ERROR', '-x', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=30', '-o', 'ControlPersist=300', '-o', 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'ServerAliveInterval=15', '-MN', '-S', '/tmp/control-channel', '-p', '22', '-l', ssh_user, 'localhost']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, env=env,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,   # enable stderr
        stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        start_new_session=True)

# wait for the ssh command to start up
process.wait(timeout=10)

# use shared socket
args2 = ['ssh', '-o', 'LogLevel=ERROR', '-o', 'ControlPath=/tmp/control-channel', '-p', '22', '-l', ssh_user, 'localhost', 'uname -a']
process2 = subprocess.Popen(args2,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
content, _ = process2.communicate()

# terminate the ssh command
process.terminate()

print(content)
```

This code will wait for the `ssh -f` command to start up for up to 10 seconds before using the shared socket. If the `ssh -f` command does not start up within 10 seconds, the code will raise a `TimeoutError` exception.

Once the shared socket is available, the code will use it to connect to the SSH server and run the `uname -a` command. The output of the `uname -a` command will be printed to the console.

Finally, the code will terminate the `ssh -f` command using the `process.terminate()` method.